# How to exclude the TR that contains the TD with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in which I take the first TR of my table and then I take all the TD of this TR. 
Now I need to modify this function: when I take the first TR I need to check that if all the TD of my TR have the class 'HD1' I need to take the second TR of the table.
I put my function below. Thanks in advance.

```
 function getColumnsIdx(id) {
   var header = $("table#" + id + " thead tr:eq(1)");
   var header_fields = $("td", header);
   var header_idx = new Object();
   header_fields.each(function(idx, val) {
     var $$ = $(val);
     var key = $$.text();
     header_idx[key] = idx;
   });
 return header_idx;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for the first `td` without that class, and then take its parent:

```
var header = $("table#" + id + " thead tr td:not(.HD1):eq(0)").parent();
```

This could, however, result in getting the third/fourth/etc row. If you must always return the second row, even if those cells also all have the HD1 class:

```
var header = $("table#" + id + " thead tr:eq(0)");
var header_fields = $("td", header);

if (header_fields.length && header_fields.length == header_fields.filter(".HD1").length) {
  header = header.next();
  header_fields = $("td", header);
}
```

Note: `:eq()` uses a zero-based index, so use `eq(0)` to select the first element.

Comment: Thank for helping me! I used this answer and It works as I expected. Do you think that if I need further help but concerning other parts of the code I can continue to write here or I need to ask another question? I'm new so i don't know which is the best way to use this forum. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'd recommend a new question. That way it'll get more attention. Also make sure it can stand on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the first row contains only `class="HD1"` elements by comparing the length of that selector to the length of the `<td>` elements in general.

If they're the same length  (all of the `<td>` are `HD1`) - use the second row. Otherwise, use the first.

**With HD1:**

```js
let $row = $("thead tr:first > .HD1").length === $("thead tr:first > td").length
  ? $("table tr").eq(1)
  : $("table tr").first();
  
$row.css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="HD1">1</td>
    <td class="HD1">2</td>
    <td class="HD1">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Without HD1:**

```js
let $row = $("thead tr:first > .HD1").length === $("thead tr:first > td").length
  ? $("table tr").eq(1)
  : $("table tr").first();
  
$row.css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```